# Decimal numbers with comma fail validation in Germany or Turkish

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, webshim

I have tried your library for number and date. date is working but number have a problem that if I use Germany language, Format is 1.234,56 I get this error: "Invalid input."
it is working but There is a validation problem. you get validation error and you cant submit
Could you fix it? type="number"
public decimal Price { get; set; }

`<input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" type="number"/>`

Also I created Turkish Language. could you add it ?
https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/issues/594

The following examples show the decimal separator and the thousands separator in various countries that use the Arabic numeral system.
http://www.wikizeroo.net/index.php?q=aHR0cHM6Ly9lbi53aWtpcGVkaWEub3JnL3dpa2kvRGVjaW1hbF9tYXJr

Comment: Welcome to SO suphi. You seem to be asking to about some library, and asking the library owner to add your contribution. I think maybe you meant to post this on Github?

Comment: Right, StackOverflow is the wrong platform for this type of request. Also don't expect anyone to reply on the linked GitHub issue, the library is marked as deprecated, which basically means its not maintained anymore and replaced by something different. But hey, its open source. You can fork it, add the changes yourself and use the forked library for your use case. Or look for an actively maintained replacement

Comment: Please take a minute to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Stackoverflow is there to help answer programming relation questions which can be answered solved. Its not good for reporting bugs and/or ask question which ask for opinions (or lead to primary opinion based answers) or ask for off-site resources (tutorials, libraries, etc)